# What's wrong in this formula when calculating it with C#?

Tags: c#, math, double, equation

I need to **calculate** a value based on a **formula** that I've checked [there](https://www.mathpapa.com/equation-solver/), as we can see in this screenshot:

[image: formula and graph]

I've tried to this **equation** in my C# app, but I don't get the expected values.

For example, I've created a basic **console app**:

```
public static void Calculate()
{
    var values = new double[] { 1, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 0};

    // y = - ((4/3) * x^3) + (3 * x^2) - ((2/3) * x)
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        var calcul1 = - ((4 / 3) * Math.Pow(value, 3))
                      + (3 * Math.Pow(value, 2))
                      - ((2 / 3) * value);

        var calcul2 = ((-4 / 3) * (value * value * value))
                      + (3 * (value * value))
                      + ((-2 / 3) * value);

        Console.WriteLine($"value: {value} - calcul1: {calcul1} / calcul2: {calcul2}");
    }
}
```

I get these results, that are not close to the expected results:

```
value: 1 - calcul1: 2 / calcul2: 2
value: 0.75 - calcul1: 1.265625 / calcul2: 1.265625
value: 0.5 - calcul1: 0.625 / calcul2: 0.625
value: 0.25 - calcul1: 0.171875 / calcul2: 0.171875
value: 0 - calcul1: 0 / calcul2: 0
```

***What's wrong? Is it related to the use of `double`?***

Comment: Integer division: `(4 / 3) == 1` but: `(4d / 3d) == 1.333..d`

Comment: Thanks @TaW, I will update this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refactored your code in order to obtain the correct values.
If you perform a division calculation without a explicit casting c# Implicitly cast to an integer, discarding the decimal part:

```
public static void Calculate()
{
    var values = new double[] { 1, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 0};

    // y = - ((4/3) * x^3) + (3 * x^2) - ((2/3) * x)
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        double firstFraction = (double)4/3;
        double secondFraction = (double)2/3;
        
        var calcul1 = - (firstFraction * Math.Pow(value, 3))
                      + (3 * Math.Pow(value, 2))
                      - (secondFraction * value);

        var calcul2 = ((firstFraction*-1) * (value * value * value))
                      + (3 * (value * value))
                      + ((secondFraction*-1) * value);

        Console.WriteLine($"value: {value} - calcul1: {calcul1} / calcul2: {calcul2}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more carefull with your data types.

as a test try to show the output for

```
var calc = (4 / 3) * 0.5;
Console.WriteLine(calc);  //-> shows 0.5
```

because 4 and 3 are integers which is a data type without decimal point, 4/3 = 1

you can force 4 and 3 to be evaluated as doubles using literals [floating point documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types)
like this:

```
var calc = (4D / 3D) * 0.5;
Console.WriteLine(calc);  //-> shows 0.666666666666667
```

see [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UQlnOC) for an online example